# Why does Felix always leave his door unlocked?

Tags: orphan-black

Throughout the series, visitors often just barge into Felix's place/crib by opening his sliding door entrance.

Why isn't Felix more cautious (especially given his deep involvement)?

Felix has also shown himself to be fairly competent and careful in helping out, so it doesn't seem like he's a consistently careless character.

Comment: I suspect that while this in part plays to plot convenience, I also think it may play a role in characterization. Felix & Sarah both come off as misfits/criminals/punks in part having to do with their upbringing and this plays into their gritty crime drama "tone" or flavor of the series.